# How to move files to another folder using variables...escape strings

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to move files from one folder to a newly created folder. When I write to the host the file and folder names are correct but the file does not move. Here is the part of the code I am having trouble with. Obviously this doesn't move the files but I have tried almost every variation trying to escape the strings.

```
$fileToMove= "$($path)\$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)"
Write-Host "File to move: $($fileToMove)"
$folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$(split-path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM d yyyy'))"
Write-Host "Folder name:$($folder)"
Move-Item '$($path)' '$($folder)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the code below:

```
$folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$($dPath)\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM d yyyy'))"
Write-Host "$dpath\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM d yyyy'))"

Move-Item "$($Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)" "$($dPath)\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM d yyyy'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - There are a few things wrong:

1 - You are using single-quotes on the 'move-item' line which prevents variable expansion.

2 - You refer to '$path' rather than '$filetomove' in the 'move-item' command.

3 - You refer to '$folder' on the 'move-item' line. '$folder' refers to an object rather than a path. PowerShell may well handle this behind the scenes but it's worth being aware of. I've modified the line to pass the full name of the folder.

I've also taken out some un-necessary $() that aren't required.

```
$fileToMove= "$path\$($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name)"
Write-Host "File to move: $fileToMove"
$folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$(split-path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM yyyy'))\$((Get-Date).ToString('MMM d yyyy'))"
Write-Host "Folder name: $folder"
Move-Item "$fileToMove" "$($folder.FullName)"
```

In fact, you should not need to use the quotes at all. Move-Item is an internal command and PowerShell will send the values of whatever it finds in the parameters, including any spaces, so the following should also work.

```
move-item $fileToMove $folder
```

Comment: still does not move the file

Comment: Can you show some example values for the $Event.SourceEventArgs properties? I tested this code but had to substitute values for those properties as I cannot replicate them. In my test, the path was created and the file was moved.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking you are using a FileSystemWatcher to call this code? If so, are you calling directly after a OnCreated event?